# csrf в yii2. Bad Request (#400): Не удалось проверить переданные данные

Tags: yii2, csrf

Подскажите, пожалуйста, может кто-то сталкивался: при добавлении на форму виджет от kartik DateControl в поле date при выборе даты, ошибка: Bad Request (#400): Не удалось проверить переданные данные.
В main.php и _form.php  добавила `<?= Html::csrfMetaTags()?>`. В контроллере если добавить:

```
    public function beforeAction($action)
    {
        //$this->enableCsrfValidation = false;
        return parent::beforeAction($action);
    }
```

ничего не меняется, выдаёт всё равно bad request, при удалении из контроллера кода выше проблема та же.

_form.php :

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\bootstrap4\ActiveForm;
use yii\helpers\Url;
use yii\widgets\Pjax;
use kartik\datecontrol\DateControl;
use app\models\DebGeneral;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use kartik\icons\Icon;
use kartik\select2\Select2;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\models\DebGeneral */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
?>
<?php $this->registerJs( $js, $position = yii\web\View::POS_READY, $key = null );
Icon::map($this, Icon::FAS);
<?= Html::csrfMetaTags() ?>
<div class="card card-primary card-outline" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
        <div class="card-header">
            <h4><i class="far fa-id-card"></i>&nbsp;<?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h4>
            <div class="card-tools"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <?php $dataList = DebGeneral::find()->asArray()->all();
            $data = ArrayHelper::map($dataList, 'executor', 'executor');
            $data1 = ArrayHelper::map($dataList, 'debtor', 'debtor');
            ?>
            <?php
                Pjax::begin([]);
                $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['data' => ['pjax' => true]]]);
            ?>
            <div class="form-group">
                <?= Html::submitButton('Сохранить', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
                <?= Html::a('Назад', ['deb-general/index', '#'=>'nav-contact'], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
                <?= Html::resetButton('Сбросить', ['class' => 'btn btn-outline-secondary']) ?>
            </div>
            <div class="row">                
                <div class="col"><?= $form->field($model, 'date')->widget(DateControl::className(), [
                        'type'=> 'date',
                        'ajaxConversion'=>true,
                        'autoWidget' => true,
                        'displayFormat' => 'php:d.m.Y',
                        'saveFormat' => 'php:Y-m-d',
                        'language' => 'ru',
                        'pluginOptions' => [
                            'autoclose'=>true,
                        ],
                    ])->label("дата заполнения *")?></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <?= Html::submitButton('Сохранить', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
                <?= Html::a('Назад', ['deb-general/index', '#'=>'nav-contact'], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
                <?= Html::resetButton('Сбросить', ['class' => 'btn btn-outline-secondary']) ?>
            </div>
            <?php ActiveForm::end();
            Pjax::end();
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php unset($this->assetBundles['yii\bootstrap4\BootstrapAsset']); ?>
```

[image: badrequest]

Comment: Покажите форму.

Comment: добавила код формы в вопрос

Comment: `Html::csrfMetaTags()` - регистрируется один раз в `<head>`, а не в каждой форме. Теперь посмотрите какой токен регистрируется в `<head>` и какой отправляет форма. Совпадают ли?

Comment: нет, не совпадают(

Answer (score 0):

Тебе нужно отправить csrf tocken вместе с ajax запросом конвертации даты. На вскидку что то вроде
var param = yii.getCsrfParam();
var token = yii.getCsrfToken();